Is there a way to implement mTLS in tomcat that will validate the leaf certificate and not just the signing authority?
We want to implement mtls in tomcat(acting as server) and it should validate the client leaf certificate
It's allowing the connection just by having the root and intermediary being added to the trust store. It doesn't care to validate the leaf certificate
